# Can I use a ES client that creates a local node and joins a cluster over TCP on Heroku?

Tags: scala, heroku, elasticsearch

I'm hoping to connect to a remote ElasticSearch cluster from a Scala app running on Heroku. I've never used ES before, but as I understand it the most efficient way to connect from Java/Scala is to create a local data-less node that joins the cluster you want to query and talks to it over its native TCP interface. Is it possible (and / or allowed) to use such a client on Heroku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at time of writing, you have to use the HTTP interface. This will restrict your choice of client libraries too.

Comment: That is the conclusion I got to too, regretfully.